# Making a web app that allows any salesforce org/user to sign up and see analytics

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, oauth

I'm creating a web application in which a user can "connect" their salesforce account to my web app and see analytics. I've currently looked at creating a connected app, but that only works for my org since that's where it was installed. I'm new to salesforce and have never used it for anything until this point. How can I accomplish this? I want any salesforce user to be able to give me access to their data.

Answer (score 0):

Connected Apps automatically "install" themselves the first time they're used in an org. You don't need to install a Connected App for each org. When a user logs in and grants access, they will have access to their org's data.